# virtuemart where can be the generated invoice pdf be modified

Tags: mysql, joomla

Where can the invoice pdf that is generated in virtuemart be modified

[image: invoice]

Comment: for print view link its fine but not for invoice.pfd the structure is a mess and invoice.php is not working

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify invoice_items.php
the template is set in controller/invoice.php and the vmfiles folder in administrator will store pdf only once ,so make sure u delete it every time you can to echo changes to pdf. if you do not delete that particular order file it will load same template again ,hence you will not understand what changes you are making because they wont be reflected.